# How to store Application state in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, silverlight-5.0

I have an Application which works totally fine when I open it once, but now the problem is if the user hits windows home key it exits the application and move my app to background. Now if the user long press back key and open my application it returns to the same page from which the user hit the home key. But if the user clicks on application icon, my app starts from the beginning which I don't want. Please help me. Thanks

Tell me where should I put code so that I get the desired result.

My App.xaml is below:
    =================

```
namespace MyProj
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        // Easy access to the root frame
        public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        // Constructor
        public App()
        {
            // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
            UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

            // Standard Silverlight initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            // Phone-specific initialization
            InitializePhoneApplication();


            // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Display the current frame rate counters.
                Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

                // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

                // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
                // which shows areas of a page that are handed off to GPU with a colored overlay.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;

                // Disable the application idle detection by setting the UserIdleDetectionMode property of the
                // application's PhoneApplicationService object to Disabled.
                // Caution:- Use this under debug mode only. Application that disable user idle detection will continue to run
                // and consume battery power when the user is not using the phone.
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
            }

        }

        // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
        // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
        private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
        // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
        private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Restart session

        }

        // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
        // This code will not execute when the application is closing
        private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
        // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
        private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
        }

        // Code to execute if a navigation fails
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        #region Phone application initialization

        // Avoid double-initialization
        private bool phoneApplicationInitialized = false;

        // Do not add any additional code to this method
        private void InitializePhoneApplication()
        {
            if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
                return;

            // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
            // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
            //RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
            RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
            RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

            // Handle navigation failures
            RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

            // Ensure we don't initialize again
            phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
        }

        // Do not add any additional code to this method
        private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
            if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
                RootVisual = RootFrame;

            // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
            RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joe Korolewicz any help regarding this, m really stucked...thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't worked with Windows Phone so I can't be much help, I was just re-tagging it for better visibility.

If you'd like a guess, I would say to create another property like your `RootFrame` that is `CurrentFrame`, and whenever you reactivate, to give it focus.

Comment: You might want to do some reading on IsolatedStorage for saving stuff after your app closes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement tombstone functionality. Just read
[App activation and deactivation for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this one, also a TomstoneHelper.dll. But when I implement everything and then starts my app, then press windows home key and then press appicon, my app restarts again..:(

Comment: "then press appicon" that mean tap to tile or long press back button and select app from pool? If you use wp7 - when you tap to app tile every app run again. Restoring from tap to tile supported only in wp8

Comment: oh is that so, then can you please help in solving my problem, actually i have to save user login session so that when user come back again in future the user login state is preserved. I have used IsolatedstorageSettings to get userProfile, but the response of user login contains a cookie container, which is used for further interactions, but when i save it in isolatedstorage, it doesnt work. Also, cookiescontainer contains blank cookie thats y i m not able to figure out whats coming and going..

Comment: You can save login/pass in IS settings. And any other serializable object directly in own file (for ex. .xml with all users activity) in Isolated Storage. Also read this if you don't know how create/store/read files in IS: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Comment: that I am doing, anyways thanks for the confirmation about windows phone 7 :)